# How do I save plotly graph as jpg

Tags: python, plotly

How do I save the following, graph created after `graph.show()`, as JPG, PNG, or PDF to a specific directory?

**The code**:

```py
    import plotly.graph_objects as go

    graph = go.Figure(data=[go.Candlestick(x=df['Date'],
                open=df['AAPL.Open'], high=df['AAPL.High'],
                low=df['AAPL.Low'], close=df['AAPL.Close'])
                      ])

    graph.show()
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This will work:

```
graph.write_image("name_of_file.jpeg")
```

But you'll have to install kaleido. From the [plotly docs](https://plotly.com/python/static-image-export/) you can see that:

```
Static image generation requires either Kaleido (recommended, supported as of plotly 4.9) or orca (legacy as of plotly 4.9). The kaleido package can be installed using pip.

$ pip install -U kaleido
```

> or conda.

```
$ conda install -c plotly python-kaleido
```

Comment: @SQL Thank you for accepting my suggestion. If you found it useful, by now you have also gained enough rep points to upvote questions and answers.

Answer (score 2):

A simple google search showed me

```
graph.write_image("name_of_file.jpeg")
```

https://plotly.com/python/static-image-export/